# How to dynamically create an html table header columns

Tags: c#

```
List<string> columsToAdd = SelectedColumns.Split(',').ToList<string>();

string tableHeader = string.Empty;
tableHeader = "<table border = 1>" +
"<thead>" +
"<tr style='font-weight:bold;background-color: #f2f8f8;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;color: #01846a;'>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Country + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.State + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.City + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item1 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item2 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item3 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item4 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item5 + "</th>" +
"</tr>" +
"</thead></table>";
```

In the above code snippet, i'm creating an html table header. How can i dynamically first check if an item exists in `List<string> columsToAdd` before adding a particular `<th>` to `string tableHeader`.

For example, i want to only add `"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item5 + "</th>" +` only if `columsToAdd` contains the string "Item5"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the existence of element by using `IndexOf` method. If `IndexOf` of some colunm is greater than 0 than add column.

```
if(columsToAdd.IndexOf(Headers.Dynamic.Country) > -1)
```

Your code should look like this

```
string tableHeader = string.Empty;
tableHeader = "<table border = 1>" +
"<thead>" +
"<tr style='font-weight:bold;background-color: #f2f8f8;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;color: #01846a;'>";

if(columsToAdd.IndexOf(Headers.Dynamic.Country) > -1)
 tableHeader +="<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Country + "</th>";

tableHeader +="<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.State + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.City + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item1 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item2 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item3 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item4 + "</th>" +
"<th>" + Headers.Dynamic.Item5 + "</th>" +
"</tr>" +
"</thead></table>";
```

Similarly you can check other columns.